# How to fix training error in yolov5 image classification

Tags: windows, image, classification, yolov5, pyhook

[enter image d[error in Training YOLOv5s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/um2Sv.png)escription here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwGjA.png)

I am working on a capstone project about image classification, and I have followed the instructions from the YOLOv5 website. However, I am still facing some challenges and I would appreciate your help on this. Please let me know if you have any suggestions or feedback for me.

Thank you!

Comment: Error is not mention in the image , add more image or paste in the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.